# how to use socks5 proxy(socksify gem) with HTTParty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty, socks5

I use rails with HTTParty for get and post requests.
I want to use SOCKS5 proxy for some requests with HTTParty.
I noticed that HTTParty doesn't support socks5 by default.
I know that socksify gem is used to connect to socks5 proxy.
but I don't know how to use socksify in HTTParty.

Answer (score 0):

add in Gemfile:

gem 'httparty', git: "https://github.com/shomid/httparty_socks.git", ref:'v0.21.1'

https://github.com/shomid/httparty_socks